# Java 8 Streams - Call "map" during stream operations without saving to variable

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I could not find many answers to this, though I suppose its not possible, but I was curious - is there anyway in Java8 streams to "refer" or to "call" the HashMap that is created via the `.collectors(Collectors.toMap(key -> "key", val -> "val")`? I know I can save this resultant reduction which creates the Map to `Map<String, String> myMap` variable, but I still had to perform operations on this resultant HashMap and I wanted to keep the stream going, so I wanted to do something like this:

```
myHashSet.stream().
.filter(i -> i != null)
.collectors(Collectors.toMap(key -> "key", val -> "val")
.forEach((k,v) -> {

   // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE MAP CREATED ABOVE
   if( MAP.contains("someRandomValue") {
    
    }


}));
```

I'm assuming you can't do this, but I was hoping there was some method or something so I don't have to "kill" the stream, i.e. save the Map to a variable, then proceed to stream it out again etc...

Comment: You can't "keep the stream going" after it's been collected. If you need to reference the map, store it in a variable and then call `forEach()`.

Comment: If you really want to avoid the extra variable, you can do `collectingAndThen(toMap(...), map -> map.forEach(...))`.

Comment: "I don't have to "kill" the stream, i.e. save the Map to a variable" - collect() is a terminal op, there is no stream after it.

Comment: @shmosel i think this is what i wanted , if you post your comment as answer I"ll accept as best answer thank you

Answer (score 4):

The `collect` operation in `Stream` is a terminal operation. So there is no `Stream` after `collect`. You would have to do something like below.

```
var myMap = myHashSet.stream().
.filter(i -> i != null)
.collectors(Collectors.toMap(key -> "key", val -> "val");

myMap.forEach((k,v) -> {

   // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL THE MAP CREATED ABOVE
   if( MAP.contains("someRandomValue") {
    
    }


}));
```

Below article describes about the available intermediate operations in `Stream`.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2020/04/java-8-stream-intermediate-operations-methods-examples.html

Comment: @shmosel also provided a good answer using collectingAndThen

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with @shmosel's help using `collectingAndThen`. This was the closest to what I wanted to do.

```
myArrayList.stream().
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.getName(), val -> val), map -> map.forEach((key, val) -> System.out.println(map.contains(key)));
```

Comment: I've misunderstood the question so will delete my answer. However I'm not sure I understand the answer either because the last parameter  `map -> map.forEach` to `collectingAndThen` isn't a Function - so this won't compile?

Comment: @DuncG Good point. You'd have to return a dummy value.